# Mixing org-mode export backends

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How can I export to a single file using several backends for different
parts of the org file?  Specifically, when exporting an org file with
a specific backend, I want to be able to export some specific elements
**using another backend**.

Long description

I want to be able to export org to a specific text file format (let's
call it amc), and for this I created a new export backend, derived
from ascii, and that works well.

Such amc files can contain latex fragments, enclosed in [latex] and
[/latex] tags.  So I would like, when exporting to amc, to export some
org elements (eg tables) using the latex backend and enclosing the
result in amc [latex] tags.

I tried to do that this way:

```
(defun org-amc-table (table contents info)
  "Transcode table as latex code inside latex AMC-TXT construct"
  (setq info (plist-put info :latex-default-table-environment "tabular"))
  (format "[latex]\n%s[/latex]" (org-latex--org-table table contents info)))
```

where `org-latex--org-table` exports an org-table to a latex table.
However, the contents of the table itself is exported through the amc
backend, not latex.  I can force the exporter to use latex export
functions for table rows and cells by specifying them in amc backend's
`translate-alist`:

```
(table . org-amc-table)
(table-row . org-latex-table-row)
(table-cell . org-latex-table-cell)
```

but the inner content of the cells is still translated by the amc
exporter (eg in a cell `*bold*` is translated to amc's bold, not
latex's `\textbf{bold}`.

How can I "call" the latex backend from the amc backend, for specific
elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally did it.  I first define a function `org-export-as-latex-string` to export any (org text) string to latex:

```
(defun org-export-as-latex-string (s)
  "Export org string as latex string."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert s)
    (let ((org-export-show-temporary-export-buffer nil)) ;; much faster!
      (with-current-buffer (org-export-to-buffer 'latex "*latex*" nil nil nil t)
    (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max))))))
```

Then I define `org-amc-table` to ignore its args, get the source of the table in the buffer and export it to a latex string with `org-export-as-latex-string` above.

```
(defun org-amc-table (table contents info)
  "Transcode table as latex code inside latex AMC-TXT construct"
  (let* ((org (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))
     (info (plist-put info :latex-default-table-environment "tabular"))
     (str (org-export-as-latex-string org)))
    (format "[latex]\n%s[/latex]" str)))
```

I initially used the `:beg` and `:end` properties of the `table`
element to get the buffer positions of the table, but I then realized
that's not necessary since the buffer that the function sees only
contains the source of the table (maybe *narrow*ing is in effect?)